# Display multiple rows of fields into multiple columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the current form of data in mysql database:-

```
| Roll No  | Semester | Sub_code | Sub_name | Sub_grade |
| -------- | -------- |--------- |----------|-----------|
| 19hhh01  | 1        |BSL 001   |    AI    |    B+     |
| 19hhh01  | 1        |CSL 2022  |    OS    |    C+     |
| 19hhh01  | 2        |IUJ 1022  |    DDS   |    A+     |
| 19hhh01  | 2        |KSJ 2012  |    KJ    |    C+     |
| 19hhh02  | 1        |BSL 001   |    AI    |    B+     |
| 19hhh02  | 1        |CSL 2022  |    OS    |    A+     |
| 19hhh02  | 2        |IUJ 1022  |    DDS   |    A+     |
| 19hhh02  | 2        |KSJ 2012  |    KJ    |    A+     |
```

This is what I actually want in output:-

| Roll No | Semester | Sub_code1 | Sub_name1 | Sub_grade1 | Sub_code2 | Sub_name2 | Sub_grade2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19hhh01 | 1 | BSL 001 | AI | B+ | CSL 2022 | OS | C+ |
| 19hhh01 | 2 | IUJ 1022 | DDS | A+ | KSJ 2012 | KJ | C+ |
| 19hhh02 | 1 | BSL 001 | AI | B+ | CSL 2022 | OS | A+ |
| 19hhh02 | 2 | IUJ 1022 | DDS | A+ | KSJ 2012 | KJ | A+ |

Kindly help me how can I achieve this using mysql query.
Thanks.

Someone marked below answer as duplicate to my question but my query is different.

```
+-----------------+------------+
| id | fieldname  | fieldvalue |
+-----------------+------------+
|  1 | size       | S          |
|  1 | height     | 103        |
|  2 | size       | L          |
|  2 | height     | 13         |
|  2 | color      | black      |
```

Here we have fieldname+id acts unique column for each id. But in my case I dont have unique column like this.

Comment: Will it never be more than 2 grades per rollno/semester?

Comment: Yes. It will go upto sub_grade12. and Semester also upto 10.